# Why possibility of rolling dice is permutation but not combination?

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations, dice

I found in many or nearly all examples or tutorials, when talking about calculating the possibility of rolling dice, e.g. possibility of getting triple 1 when rolling 3 6-faces dices, are calculating with permutation, i.e. answer is 1 / (no. of possible outcomes) = 1 / 6 x 6 x 6 = 1/216

I'm very confused for that: why everyone is treating it as permutation, while the order of dice does not matter / assuming that the dices are indistinguishable ?

Answer (score 2):

If we treat them as "permutations", every case would have an equal probability. For example, $$\mathbb P(1,2,1)=\mathbb P(2,1,1)=\frac{1}{216}$$
If we treated the above two cases as the same case (i.e. treating both cases as getting one 2 and two 1s), then each case would have different probabilities, which leads to trouble in calculations. For example, $$\mathbb P(\text{getting one 2 and two 1s})\ne \mathbb P(\text{getting one 1, one 2, one 3})$$
while we have something like $$\mathbb P(1,2,1)=\mathbb P(2,1,1)=\mathbb P(1,2,3)=\mathbb P(3,2,1)=\frac{1}{216}$$

Comment: what i actually confusing is the total number of possible outcome: 216
why do we count the outcome [1,1,2] & [1,2,1] as different and mutually exclusive outcomes, while the dice are identical; just like if we actually throwing 3 indistinguishable dices at the same time, we cannot tell whether the outcome is [1,1,2] or [1,2,1]

Comment: @WongJacky the probability of each outcome is the same ONLY IF we treat each of the 216 outcomes differently, as I explained above

Comment: yes, so my question should be, why are we treating the outcome [1,1,2] & [1,2,1] are different
it is 216 outcomes only when treating [1,1,2] & [1,2,1] as difference outcomes

Comment: My standard rant:  "Dices" is a verb meaning to cut into small cubes.   In the context here, "dice" is itself the plural of "die".

Comment: You can consider that you have 3 dice, with different colors : bleu red green.  [1,1,2] is the result of [Blue1, Red1, Green2] , or [Blue1,Red2, Green1] or [Blue2, Red1, Green1] ; it is 3 different events. [1,1,1] can be obtained only with [Blue1, Red1, Green1]. And it is easy to check that [1,2,3] correspond to 6 events. When you have to deal with dice and probabilities, always consider that your dice have different colors.